# So basically I was working on supabase. After I generate the access token I copied it and pasted it in the terminal but invalid access token showing

Tags: supabase

So basically i want help to fix the problem invalid access token showing error

I think it is probably a version error or any copy paste error please specify it to me if anyone is facing the same problem. I cannot even copy paste the access token in my terminal nor can i write it down manually.